# Where does this approximation for the expected value of an exponential come from?

Tags: integration, probability-theory, taylor-expansion, brownian-motion, stochastic-integrals

I have seen the following approximation in a number of papers recently, but I cannot figure out where it comes from. The approximation is as follows

> Let $W_t$ be a standard Brownian motion and $f$ some smooth, positive function. Then we can make the following approximation $$\mathbb{E}\left[\exp\left(\int^t_0 \frac{1}{f(W_u)} du\right)\Big|W_t = z\right] = \exp\left(\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{f(0)} + \frac{1}{f(z)}\right)t\right) + \mathcal{O}(t^2)$$ where $\mathcal{O}(t^2)$ is a term that groups together all terms of order $t^2$ or higher.

I figured this must be some sort of Taylor series approximation, but then terms are always missing w.r.t. the expression on the right hand side above.

Another thought I had was that the approximation looks a lot like some moment generating function, more specifically that of a normal distribution, but this also led to nothing.

Any tips are appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like the Trapezoid Rule approximation of the integral of a continuous function, with one interval: If $g$ is twice differnetiable on $[0,t]$ then
$$
\int_0^t g(u)\,du = {g(0)+g(t)\over 2}\cdot t + {t^3\over 12}g''(\xi),
$$
for some $\xi\in (0,t)$. This can't be applied directly to $I(t):=\int_0^t 1/f(W_u)\,du$, but it can be used after taking expectations. As a start, write $J(t)=t[1/f(0)+1/f(z)]/2$ and $\Delta (t) =I(t)-J(t)$. Then $J(t)\to 0$ as $t\to 0$, and so
$$
\exp(I(t))-\exp(J(t))=\left[\exp(\Delta(t))-1\right]\cdot\exp(J(t)).
$$
and, as $J(t)$ is nonrandom,  it is enough to examine $\Bbb E\left[\exp(\Delta(t))-1\mid W(t)=z\right]$. For this expand the exponential in its Maclaurin series. The first order term is $\mathscr O(t^3)$ by the Trapezoid Rule with error term noted above. The sum of the remaining terms is easily seen to be $\mathscr O(t^2)$ because $|\Delta(t)|\le Ct\|1/f\|_\infty$ for a suitable constant $C$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! You are correct indeed, but why can't the rule be directly applied to $I(t)$?

Comment: Because the Brownian motion isn't differentiable.

Comment: Alright. I will try to work everything out tomorrow and accept your answer accordingly. Thanks again!

Comment: It all makes sense, but I have a question about the part where you say "the first order term is $\mathcal{O}(t^3)$ by the Trapezoid Rule with error term noted above.". You said earlier we cannot apply the Trapezoid Rule because the Brownian motion is not differentiable, so how come we can still say $\int^t_0 \frac{1}{f(W_u)}du - J(t) = \mathcal{O}(t^3)$?

Comment: Because if we use that logic, we might aswell directly state that $\int^t_0 \frac{1}{f(W_u)}du = J_t + \mathcal{O}(t^3)$.

Comment: That comes from applying the Trap. Rule to the *expected value* of $\Delta(t)$, not to $\Delta(t)$ itself.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean? I basically end up with the following: $$\Bbb E\left[\exp(\Delta(t))-1\mid W(t)=z\right]$$ then applying the Maclaurin expansion gives $$\Bbb E\left[1 + \Delta(t) + \mathcal{O}(t^2)-1\mid W(t)=z\right]$$ then applying what you mentioned gives $$\Bbb E\left[1 +\mathcal{O}(t^3) + \mathcal{O}(t^2)-1\mid W(t)=z\right]$$ which finally gives $$\Bbb E\left[\mathcal{O}(t^2)\mid W(t)=z\right]$$ which I cannot do anything with. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: That final term should be $\mathscr O(t^2)$, which is what you want, no?